How to propagate properties to a consuming library in CMake?
I want to create an interface library that contains a bunch of settings in my CMake setup so that all of my libraries (or at least the ones I want, e.g. not tests perhaps) can have uniform settings.
I'm trying to use the warning as error property to automatically turn on the relevant setting for the particular compiler.
My problem: I can't figure out how to get this to propagate to the "child" or "consuming" library.
# Setting up the interface library
add_library(options_lib INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET options_lib APPEND PROPERTY COMPATIBLE_INTERFACE_BOOL COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR)
set_target_properties(options_lib PROPERTIES COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR ON)
...
add_library(my_actual_lib PUBLIC src/foo.cpp)
# Note: results seem to be the same even if I do PRIVATE
target_link_library(my_actual_lib PUBLIC options_lib)

get_target_property(result my_actual_lib COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR)
message(STATUS "Result: ${result}")

This produces result-NOTFOUND as the result.
Is there a better way to propagate this setting? Am I missing something in this setup?

You should not do this. Let the user of the library decide how to treat warnings.

@usr1234567 I get your point and agree, but to be clear, this is not meant for exporting the library or anything. It is for my own internal use to synchronize settings across myriad independent little libraries in a larger project. This is supposed to be similar to how project_options is set up: https://github.com/aminya/project_options

Propagation of properties occurs at the very end of configuration process (generation stage). With get_target_property you cannot check the results of propagation - this command extracts value of the property immediately, when the propagation hasn't been performed yet. Instead, refer to the property via generator expression $<TARGET_PROPERTY:my_actual_lib,COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR>, and use one of the method for output its value.
